# Use two Itextsharp versions in same project

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am working on intranet portal where there are many subsystems are linked to the portal . Now the portal is newly developed on .net 4.0 .I have used itextsharp version 5.5.9 in this portal .

Pdf generation is working fine in the project but the problem is when I merge old subsystems with this portal , there's a conflict in itextsharp versions as there's so many things which are **not supported in itextsharp 5.5.9** version For Example :

1. **HeaderFooter** footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(
2. myParagraph.**SetAlignment**
3. iTextSharp.text.**Table** tableh = new iTextSharp.text.Table(11);
4. **Cell** csr = new Cell(sr);

Above are some examples which are not supported in itextsharp newer versions .

More than 5 subsystems are using itextsharp old version .

As there are so many subsystems to be merged in the portal , I want the way where I could use both the versions of itextsharp .

Is it possible ?

Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: The `HeaderFooter` class was removed in commit 2950cbc1b1f on 06 Dec 2009: https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/commit/2950cbc1b1f. That's *ancient*! I'm guessing that your old iTextSharp versions are pre-5.x.x, probably 4.1.6. See Bruno's answer below for a detailed solution.

Comment: yes the older version is 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions to your problem.

**Solution #1:** upgrade to the latest version instead of to 5.5.9

You can't use 5.5.9 together with an older version because all of those versions use the same package names. There will be naming conflicts (as you have experienced).

However iText 7 for C# is a complete rewrite of iTextSharp and because of this, we chose different package names. There will be no conflicts when you use iText 7 next to an older version.

This means that you have to rewrite your current version.

**Solution #2:** rewrite the old code so that it works with iText 5.5.9.

The code that is used by the older applications [should not be used in production environments](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5), hence you really should upgrade those applications.

The `HeaderFooter` class was abandoned in favor of using page events. The `Table` and `Cell` class were replaced with `PdfPTable` and `PdfPCell`. I don't know about `myParagraph.SetAlignment()`, but it wouldn't surprise me if it's now `myParagraph.Alignment`.

**Conclusion:** both "solutions" require quite some work, but your company seems to have been using iTextSharp for a mighty long time, so it's about time to upgrade anyway.

Comment: Thanks alot sir for the suggestions , If I use itext version 7 , will it support all the features in itext 5.5.9 so I could not write the code for newly created apps ?

Comment: iText 7 will require you to rewrite all your code, but all the feature in 5.5.9 exist in iText 7, except for XML Worker (the new XML Worker for iText 7 will be released in about a month). Some of the iText 7 components are also made closed source (e.g. pdfCalligraph) because some people keep on thinking that "free / open source software" is "software that is *for free*". iText is licensed under the AGPL which means that you may have to purchase a license if you use it in a commercial context. Making parts of iText closed source avoids that confusion.

Comment: Make sure you read the [jump-start](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net) and [building blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks) tutorials, because iText 7 is quite different from iText 5.